# Need some help with HTTPS, certificates and signing

Tags: asp.net, iis, https

I am quite new to HTTPS and can not get my head around it.

Can someone suggest good starting point for learning about HTTPS, certificates and signing?

Possibly with a working example in ASP.NET with IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is have your site in HTTPS there is no code needed. All you need to do is set IIS to serve pages with HTTPS.

If that is all you want, you are better off asking this question in http://www.serverfault.com.

To get you started, here's a link on how to set https in iis 7: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-setup-ssl-on-iis-70/

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is just normal HTTP traffic that is encrypted using SSL/TLS. The protocol is fairly straightforward. I wrote a detailed blow-by-blow of what happens at the start of a connection on my blog: [The First First Few Milliseconds of an HTTPS Connection](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html).

It's unfortunate that the APIs built on top of the protocol are often much more complicated.